# PHP Reliable Calculating of Cube Root

Tags: php, math, floating-point-precision

It seems like a no brainer but I am having trouble to get this solved:

I would like to calculate a level based on given experience points (exp). Therefore I use the cube root formula and round down to the next whole number. The next level is reached when exp exactly reaches `level^3`. The number of levels is unlimited, so I would avoid having a pre-calculated lookup table.

When I use the standard php math

```
floor( pow( 10648, 1/3))
```

It returns 21 instead of 22. This is wrong since 21^3 gives 92161. The reason is that due to limited floating point precision pow(10648, 1/3) returns not exactly 22, instead it returns 21.9993112732.
You can check it out with the following snippet:

```
$lvl = pow( 10647, (float) 1 / 3);
print number_format( $lvl, 10);
```

This is my workaround. But I am not sure if this is bulletproof:

```
public static function getLevel($exp) {    
    $lvl = floor(pow($exp, (float) 1 / 3));    // calculate the level
    if (pow($lvl + 1, 3) == $exp) {            // make check
        $lvl++;                                // correct 
    }
    return $lvl;
}
```

Also it looks a bit fragile when it comes to the check. So the question remains: 
Is there a reliable, efficient and bulletproof way of calculating cube root (of positive numbers).

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `round()` instead of `floor()`?

Comment: `round()` also fails in certain cases. Take 7 for example. It should return level 1 but `round( pow( 7, (float) 1 / 3))` returns 2 (wrong)

Comment: The real problem is that `1/3` can't be represented exactly in floating point.

Comment: How about using 0.333334 instead of 1/3? It works for both 10647 and 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the only modification your code needs:

```
public static function getLevel($exp) {    
    $lvl = floor(pow($exp, (float) 1 / 3));    
    if (pow($lvl + 1, 3) <= $exp) {   // compare with <= instead of ==         
        $lvl++;                                 
    }
    return $lvl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need 100% reliable results, you should probably use the [GMP library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) for arbitrary precision calculations.

The [`gmp_root`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-root.php) function should do what you need.  You'll need PHP version 5.6 or newer with the GMP extension enabled.

```
$num = gmp_init(10648);
$third_root = gmp_root($num, 3);

var_dump(gmp_strval($third_root));  // string(2) "22"
```

If the GMP library is inconvenient for you and you're guaranteed that your number has an integer root then you can try the following:

```
function getLevel($base, $root = 3.0) {
    $exact = pow($base, 1.0 / $root);
    $ceil  = ceil($exact);
    $floor = floor($exact);
    
    if (pow($exact, $root) == $base) { return $exact; }
    if (pow($ceil,  $root) == $base) { return $ceil;  }
    if (pow($floor, $root) == $base) { return $floor; }
    
    // Default: no integer root
    return FALSE;
}
```

It checks the exact, `floor`, and `ceil` values of the result to find which is the correct answer.  If it's not one of the three then the number has no integer root and defaults to `FALSE`.

Here's an [example of it in action](http://ideone.com/VoABZx):

```
var_dump(getLevel(10648, 3)); // 22^3 => float(22)
var_dump(getLevel(16807, 5)); //  7^5 => float(7)
 
var_dump(getLevel(1,  3)); // Should always return 1 => float(1)
var_dump(getLevel(1, 99)); // Should always return 1 => float(1)
 
var_dump(getLevel(7)); // Has no integer 3rd root => bool(false)
```

Of course, you can make the function `return $floor;` or `return $ceil;` as the default case, but that's up to you.